# android studio preview size not same as actual size

Tags: android, android-studio, textfield, android-spinner

In android studio I have a Spinner and a text field in the same linear layout. They are both at an equal weight at 1. In android preview I get this, the
[spinner and text field are the same size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6v7Ur.png)

but when I load up my device I actually get [the spinner tiny and the text field big](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiUQQ.png)

Here is my code

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:id="@id/linearLayout">

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"
        android:entries="@array/State"
        android:layout_marginTop="110sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="999999999"
        android:layout_marginTop="130sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:spinnerMode="dialog"
    android:entries="@array/State"
    android:layout_marginTop="110sp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:ems="999999999"
    android:layout_marginTop="130sp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Notice the `android:layout_width="0dp"`.

Let the ART use the weights to distribute the fields based on your `layout:weight` values.

Comment: I did not realize that I was not using the weights properly. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped. Android is full of odd little (often undocumented) things like this.

Answer (score 0):

remove this line

```
 android:layout_marginTop="130sp"
```

its making top margin.

some time preview need to refresh switch between **text and desing**